# When creating a new project from scratch, browser errors with "foundation is not a function"

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

After creating a brand new foundation 6 application with `foundation new`, building the application with `foundation build`, and loading the application in the web browser, I see the following error on the developer console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: o(...)(...).foundation is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (app.js:formatted:4175)
    at o (app.js:formatted:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:formatted:4166)
    at o (app.js:formatted:11)
    at app.js:formatted:71
    at app.js:formatted:72
```

What gives? It seems like the minifier lost a reference to jquery, because this line seems to correlate to the only line in the generated `app.js` that calls the `.foundation()` function.

versions on windows. browser is a late chrome.

```
$ foundation -v; npm -v; node -v; webpack -v
Foundation CLI version 2.2.5
6.4.1
v8.11.1
4.26.1
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr: use the `Foundation` variable, like this in `app.js`

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import whatInput from 'what-input'
window.$ = $
import Foundation from 'foundation-sites'
if (Foundation) {
  // if `Foundation` is left as an unused variable
  // webpack will exclude it from the build output;
  // therefore, any expression that uses it will work.
}
$(document).foundation()
```

## for the curious

here's how i found the answer

### find the right source map settings

it took some tweaking, but i found the right source map settings for devtool. change the webpackConfig to `devtool: 'eval'` in `gulpfile.babel.js` and build for production with `$ gulp build --production` or `$ foundation build`. you want the eval setting to be used in production.

### inspect the source

the browser is still throwing exceptions on the undefined `foundation`, but this time you see who was supposed to define it.

marking up the code with comments after the call that brings in `Foundation` from `"foundation-sites"`, and building that, then reloading the browser, here's the content of `app.js` after it's been minified and source mapped:

```
// app.js comment i added
...
import Foundation from 'foundation-sites' // here, right?
...


// app.js minified
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(0);
/* harmony import */ var jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
/* harmony import */ var what_input__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(4);
/* harmony import */ var what_input__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(what_input__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);


window.$ = jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a;
 // here, right?

jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(document).foundation();
```

and now the error we get in the console is about that last line: `Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).foundation is not a function`

### that's crazy, where's `Foundation`?

i guess webpack will skip importing Foundation entirely, unless you actually use it in your entry-point code. after guessing that this was the case, i added console statement that printed the `console.info(Foundation)` and bingo. suddenly Foundation Sites imported.